# Format text from "HELLO, WORLD. HOW ARE YOU?" to "Hello, world. How are you?" in ObjC(iOS)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, format, capitalization

As the title said, I need to format a string of text in format like:  "HELLO, WORLD. HOW ARE YOU?"  into  "Hello, world. How are you?", is there any standard method for doing this in iOS? Or is there any sample code ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to capitalize the first characters of sentences in a paragraph. *NSString* just has a method *capitalizedString* which capitalizes each and every word. You have to create your own logic to achieve this. You can try the following code.

```
- (NSString *)captilizeParagraph:(NSString *)paragraph {

    if ([paragraph length] == 0) return paragraph;
    NSArray *sentences = [paragraph componentsSeparatedByString:@". "];
    NSMutableArray *capitalizedSentences = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *sentence in sentences) {

        sentence = [sentence lowercaseString];
        sentence = [sentence stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[sentence substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
        [capitalizedSentences addObject:sentence];
    }

    NSString *capitalizedParagrah = [capitalizedSentences componentsJoinedByString:@". "];
    return capitalizedParagrah;
}
```

*Note:* The above code assumes that all the sentences in the paragraph ends with characters `". "` (a dot and a space) except the last sentence(it can end with any character). If a sentence ends with some other characters like `"? "` or `"! "`, then this method will return a not-fully-formatted string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to improve it to suit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: what if I replace [paragraph componentsSeparatedByString:@". "]; with [paragraph componentsSeparatedByString:@".?! "]; ?

Comment: No. If you do like that, it will split the strings only if they end exactly with the string `@".?! "`. You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?!."]`, but after capitalizing, it will be difficult for you to join them again into *capitalizedParagrah*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know standard method to do this, and I don't think there is one.
But the `NSString` provides methods such : `-(NSString *)capitalizedString;` which returns a new string, with the **first character of each word** in upper case. After breaking correctly your string you could use it. Also think of getting a string in lower case using : `-(NSString *)lowercaseString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *)normalizeString{
    __block NSString *string = [self lowercaseString];
    string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[[string substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[\\p{P}-[,]]" options:0 error:nil];
    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result.range.location + 2 < string.length) string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(result.range.location + 2, 1) withString:[[self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(result.range.location + 2, 1)] uppercaseString]];
    }];

    return string;
}
```

Assuming that 2 characters after the punctuation is the first character of the next sentence, this works.